# LibGDX text not centered in smaller viewport

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working on a LibGDX game which uses a smaller viewport.

```
public static float BOX_SCALE = 10;
public static final float VIRTUAL_WIDTH = (int) (320 / BOX_SCALE);
public static final float VIRTUAL_HEIGHT = (int) (480 / BOX_SCALE);

float viewportHeight = MyConstants.Screen.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT;
float viewportWidth = MyConstants.Screen.VIRTUAL_HEIGHT * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

For example my viewport can have the size (32, 48). I use Scene2D for rendering. For some reason whenever i create a TextButton the text is never centered. This is the BitmapFont used for the button.

```
FreeTypeFontParameter fontParam = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
fontParam.size = 14;        

FreeTypeFontGenerator generator2 = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("data/font.ttf"));
labelFont = generator2.generateFont(fontParam);
labelFont.setScale(1f / BOX_SCALE); 
labelFont.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

[image]

If i set the BOX_SCALE value to 1 then TextButton acts normal but i need for simulating the Box2D world. I guess i could create separate labels for each button and position them manually but I can't figure out why this is happening. Also interested if there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default, font positions are rounded off to nearest world game unit. This is based on an assumption that your font will render pixel perfect. In your case, you don't want a pixel perfect font, so call:

```
labelFont.setUseIntegerPositions(false);
```

Also, in your `fontParam` you should set it to use mipmaps, and set the `minFilter` to MipmapLinearNearest and the `magFilter` to Linear. That'll make it look better, since by default the filtering is set to Nearest/Nearest which looks bad if you aren't rendering pixel perfect.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The filter part makes the text look better but using setUseIntegerPositions to false still didn't fix the problem.